# Interaction.Behaviors не работает в AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonia, wpf-commands

пишу очень примитивную версию редактора кода
здесь у меня TextBox который должен сохранять записанные данные в файл при триггере event'а TextChanged

использую AvaloniaUI и CommunityToolkit.Mvvm;

TextBox выглядит так (в axaml файле) :

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" RowDefinitions="3*, *">
                <TextBox
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    AcceptsTab="True"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Text="{Binding Code}">
                    
                    <Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                            <InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FileSaveChangesCommand}"/>
                        </EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interaction.Behaviors>>
                    

                </TextBox>
```

FileSaveChangesCommand к которой он биндится выглядит так:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void FileSaveChanges() {
    if (CurrentSelectedPath != null)
    {
            File.WriteAllText(CurrentSelectedPath, Code);
    }
}
```

Property самого кода(в TextBox):

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string? _code;
```

Comment: А смысл в `Behavior`? У вас есть привязанное свойство, которое постоянно изменяется вслед за вводом пользователя, а значит вы можете в его `set` прописать вызов нужной логики, либо INPC событие ловить и так отслеживать изменение, ну а с `CommunityToolkit` так и вовсе, все это делается за вас, вам достаточно "дописать" нужный метод, а именно пишете в классе где `_code` слово `partial` жмете пробел и вам студия дает [варианты на выбор](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRQKk.png), выбираете нужный (например `partial void OnCodeChanged(string? value) {}`) и прописываете там свою логику.

Comment: Но замечу, что дергать диск и записывать файл по каждому чиху, особенно через `File.WriteAllText` - это очень плохая затея. Тут лучше открывать `Stream` и держать файл открытым до тех пор, пока не завершиться редактирование. Также не на "каждый чих", а я бы сделал задержку, условно "если были изменения и прошло 10 сек, пишем", а еще лучше, сделать горячую клавишу сохранения (стандартно Ctrl+S) и по ее нажатию сохранять.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Как вы это поняли? И верно пишут `Interaction.Behaviors` это костыль.

Comment: OnCodeChanged сделать не дошло, спасибо, попробую.